# How to get position/off-set of an element in android with respect to parent element?

Tags: android-layout, position, android

In my project I have a layout like:

```
<FrameLayout>   ---------(1)
  <SurfaceView>
     <FrameLayout> ------(2)
  </SurfaceView>
</FrameLayout>
```

I want to access position/offset of frame-layout `(2)` with respect to frame-layout `(1)`.

When I try FrameLayout1.getLeft() and FrameLayout1.getTop(), I get it as zero.

What is the correct way to get the `(left,top)` of nested elements?

Thank you!

Update--->

```
int dpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

int offset1 = childFrameLayoutPosition[0] - rootFrameLayoutPosition[0]; //x offset
int offset2 = childFrameLayoutPosition[1] - rootFrameLayoutPosition[1]; //y offset

      //F1 is child FrameLayout
        newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,offset1*w, offset2*w,F1.getWidth()*w,F1.getHeight()*w);
```

After doing this, I got error that Width and Height parameters should be less than width and height of bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[] rootFrameLayoutPosition = new int[2];
int[] childFrameLayoutPosition = new int[2];
rootFrameLayout.getLocationInWindow(rootFrameLayoutPosition);
childFrameLayout.getLocationInWindow(childFrameLayoutPosition);
int offset = childFrameLayoutPosition[1] - rootFrameLayoutPosition[1];
```

maybe I'm confused x and y

Comment: The index0 in array int[] gives x and index1 gives y. This solution worked for me, thank you!

Comment: I have another question,when I used these co-ordinates for image cropping by method: `Bitmap.createBitmap(src,int,int,int,int)` the cropped image is not the part within frame-layout indicated. Am I missing some dp to pixel conversion?

Comment: bitmap it  background or src for ImageView?

Comment: For ImageView. For time being I am just storing the cropped image in SD card.

Comment: Try setting ScaleType for ImageView `.setScaleType()`. Try different, it should help you

Comment: `.setScaleType()` is for setting the image in ImageView. My question is about cropping the image.The image after crop is not matching with the given co-ordinates.

Comment: It seems I did not understand))

Comment: Can you please see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665793/how-to-crop-image-with-the-help-of-co-ordinates-of-template)? I posted the details

Comment: i have seen. Have you tried to offset multiplied by DPI?