# How to crop image with the help of co-ordinates of template

Tags: android, image, bitmap, crop

In my project, I am using nested `FrameLayout`. I have layout of activity as:

```
<FrameLayout>   ---------(1)
  <SurfaceView>
     <FrameLayout> ------(2)
  </SurfaceView>
</FrameLayout>
```

`FrameLayout(2)`shows a template. The activity captures image with custom camera API. The  The user is supposed to fit the object of interst in template of `FrameLayout(2)`. After the image is captured, I want to crop that image such that only the object of interest that was fitted in template is available. The original image is overwritten by this cropped image.

To crop image, I am using `Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,int,int,int,int)`. For the four  `int` parameters, I am using `getLocationInWindow(int[])` and `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`. The code is:

```
private class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {

     //Child frame-layout-
        final FrameLayout F1=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.F1);

     //Parent frame-layout-
        final FrameLayout F=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

        int a[]=new int[2];


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... data) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;

            // Write to SD Card
            try
            {

                Bitmap bitmap;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename_with_path);
                Bitmap newBitmap;

                if (bitmap != null) {

                 // child frame-layoout
                    F1.getLocationOnScreen(a);

                    newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,a[0], a[1],F1.getWidth(),F1.getHeight());

                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    newBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);


                    // overwrite original image
                    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(filename_with_path);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();

                    bitmap.recycle();
                }
                refreshGallery(outFile);
            }
            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}

            return null;
        }
    }
```

But after executing this code I am not getting desired cropped image. Instead of getting object of interest, the cropped image contains different portion of original image.

Are the units of int parameters of `Bitmap.createBitmap()` and int[] returned by`getLocationOnScreen()` different?

Do we need any conversion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is the canvas crop class

```
package com.domp.me;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;

public class TouchView extends View {

    //private final String TAG = "TESTTESTTESTESTTESTESTEST";

    private Drawable mLeftTopIcon;
    private Drawable mRightTopIcon;
    private Drawable mLeftBottomIcon;
    private Drawable mRightBottomIcon;

    private boolean mLeftTopBool = false;
    private boolean mRightTopBool = false;
    private boolean mLeftBottomBool = false;
    private boolean mRightBottomBool = false;

    // Starting positions of the bounding box

    private float mLeftTopPosX = 30;
    private float mLeftTopPosY = 120;

    private float mRightTopPosX = 150;
    private float mRightTopPosY = 120;

    private float mLeftBottomPosX = 30;
    private float mLeftBottomPosY = 200;

    private float mRightBottomPosX = 150;
    private float mRightBottomPosY = 200;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;

    private Paint topLine;
    private Paint bottomLine;
    private Paint leftLine;
    private Paint rightLine;

    private Rect buttonRec;

    private int mCenter;

    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    // you can ignore this 
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;


    public TouchView(Context context){
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super (context,attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {

        // I need to create lines for the bouding box to connect

        topLine = new Paint();
        bottomLine = new Paint();
        leftLine = new Paint();
        rightLine = new Paint();

        setLineParameters(Color.WHITE,2);

        // Here I grab the image that will work as the corners of the bounding
        // box and set their positions.

        mLeftTopIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.corners);

        mCenter = mLeftTopIcon.getMinimumHeight()/2;
        mLeftTopIcon.setBounds((int)mLeftTopPosX, (int)mLeftTopPosY,
                mLeftTopIcon.getIntrinsicWidth()+(int)mLeftTopPosX,
                mLeftTopIcon.getIntrinsicHeight()+(int)mLeftTopPosY);

        mRightTopIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.corners);
        mRightTopIcon.setBounds((int)mRightTopPosX, (int)mRightTopPosY,
                mRightTopIcon.getIntrinsicWidth()+(int)mRightTopPosX,
                mRightTopIcon.getIntrinsicHeight()+(int)mRightTopPosY);

        mLeftBottomIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.corners);
        mLeftBottomIcon.setBounds((int)mLeftBottomPosX, (int)mLeftBottomPosY,
                mLeftBottomIcon.getIntrinsicWidth()+(int)mLeftBottomPosX,
                mLeftBottomIcon.getIntrinsicHeight()+(int)mLeftBottomPosY);

        mRightBottomIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.corners);
        mRightBottomIcon.setBounds((int)mRightBottomPosX, (int)mRightBottomPosY,
                mRightBottomIcon.getIntrinsicWidth()+(int)mRightBottomPosX,
                mRightBottomIcon.getIntrinsicHeight()+(int)mRightBottomPosY);
        // Create our ScaleGestureDetector
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

    }

    private void setLineParameters(int color, float width){

        topLine.setColor(color);
        topLine.setStrokeWidth(width);

        bottomLine.setColor(color);
        bottomLine.setStrokeWidth(width);

        leftLine.setColor(color);
        leftLine.setStrokeWidth(width);

        rightLine.setColor(color);
        rightLine.setStrokeWidth(width);

    }

    // Draws the bounding box on the canvas. Every time invalidate() is called
    // this onDraw method is called.
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();

        canvas.drawLine(mLeftTopPosX+mCenter, mLeftTopPosY+mCenter,
                mRightTopPosX+mCenter, mRightTopPosY+mCenter, topLine);
        canvas.drawLine(mLeftBottomPosX+mCenter, mLeftBottomPosY+mCenter,
                mRightBottomPosX+mCenter, mRightBottomPosY+mCenter, bottomLine);
        canvas.drawLine(mLeftTopPosX+mCenter,mLeftTopPosY+mCenter,
                mLeftBottomPosX+mCenter,mLeftBottomPosY+mCenter,leftLine);
        canvas.drawLine(mRightTopPosX+mCenter,mRightTopPosY+mCenter,
                mRightBottomPosX+mCenter,mRightBottomPosY+mCenter,rightLine);


        mLeftTopIcon.setBounds((int)mLeftTopPosX, (int)mLeftTopPosY,
                mLeftTopIcon.getIntrinsicWidth()+(int)mLeftTopPosX,
                mLeftTopIcon.getIntrinsicHeight()+(int)mLeftTopPosY);

        mRightTopIcon.setBounds((int)mRightTopPosX, (int)mRightTopPosY,
                mRightTopIcon.getIntrinsicWidth()+(int)mRightTopPosX,
                mRightTopIcon.getIntrinsicHeight()+(int)mRightTopPosY);

        mLeftBottomIcon.setBounds((int)mLeftBottomPosX, (int)mLeftBottomPosY,
                mLeftBottomIcon.getIntrinsicWidth()+(int)mLeftBottomPosX,
                mLeftBottomIcon.getIntrinsicHeight()+(int)mLeftBottomPosY);

        mRightBottomIcon.setBounds((int)mRightBottomPosX, (int)mRightBottomPosY,
                mRightBottomIcon.getIntrinsicWidth()+(int)mRightBottomPosX,
                mRightBottomIcon.getIntrinsicHeight()+(int)mRightBottomPosY);


        mLeftTopIcon.draw(canvas);
        mRightTopIcon.draw(canvas);
        mLeftBottomIcon.draw(canvas);
        mRightBottomIcon.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }


    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        boolean intercept = true;

        switch (action) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            // in CameraPreview we have Rect rec. This is passed here to return
            // a false when the camera button is pressed so that this view ignores
            // the touch event.
            if ((x >= buttonRec.left) && (x <=buttonRec.right) && (y>=buttonRec.top) && (y<=buttonRec.bottom)){
                intercept = false;
                break;
            }

            // is explained below, when we get to this method.
            manhattanDistance(x,y);

            // Remember where we started
            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();
            //Log.i(TAG,"x: "+x);
            //Log.i(TAG,"y: "+y);

            // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
            // but we ignore here because we are not using ScaleGestureDetector.
            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                invalidate();
            }

            // Calculate the distance moved
            final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
            final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;


            // Move the object
            if (mPosX >= 0 && mPosX <=800){
                mPosX += dx;
            }
            if (mPosY >=0 && mPosY <= 480){
                mPosY += dy;
            }

            // while its being pressed n it does not overlap the bottom line or right line
            if (mLeftTopBool && ((y+mCenter*2) < mLeftBottomPosY) && ((x+mCenter*2) < mRightTopPosX)){
                if (dy != 0){
                    mRightTopPosY = y;
                }
                if (dx != 0){
                    mLeftBottomPosX = x;
                }
                mLeftTopPosX = x;//mPosX;
                mLeftTopPosY = y;//mPosY;
            }
            if (mRightTopBool && ((y+mCenter*2) < mRightBottomPosY) && (x > (mLeftTopPosX+mCenter*2))){
                if (dy != 0){
                    mLeftTopPosY = y;
                }
                if (dx != 0){
                    mRightBottomPosX = x;
                }
                mRightTopPosX = x;//mPosX;
                mRightTopPosY = y;//mPosY;
            }
            if (mLeftBottomBool && (y > (mLeftTopPosY+mCenter*2)) && ((x +mCenter*2) < mRightBottomPosX)){
                if (dx != 0){
                    mLeftTopPosX = x;
                }
                if (dy != 0){
                    mRightBottomPosY = y;
                }
                mLeftBottomPosX = x;
                mLeftBottomPosY = y;
            }
            if (mRightBottomBool && (y > (mLeftTopPosY+mCenter*2)) && (x > (mLeftBottomPosX+mCenter*2) )){
                if (dx != 0){
                    mRightTopPosX = x;
                }
                if (dy != 0){
                    mLeftBottomPosY = y;
                }
                mRightBottomPosX = x;
                mRightBottomPosY = y;
            }

            // Remember this touch position for the next move event
            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            // Invalidate to request a redraw
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            // when one of these is true, that means it can move when onDraw is called
            mLeftTopBool = false;
            mRightTopBool = false;
            mLeftBottomBool = false;
            mRightBottomBool = false;
            //mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            // Extract the index of the pointer that left the touch sensor
            final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
            >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
        }
        }
        return intercept;
    }

    // Where the screen is pressed, calculate the distance closest to one of the 4 corners
    // so that it can get the pressed and moved. Only 1 at a time can be moved.
    private void manhattanDistance(float x, float y) {

        double leftTopMan = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((Math.abs((double)x-(double)mLeftTopPosX)),2)
                + Math.pow((Math.abs((double)y-(double)mLeftTopPosY)),2));

        double rightTopMan = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((Math.abs((double)x-(double)mRightTopPosX)),2)
                + Math.pow((Math.abs((double)y-(double)mRightTopPosY)),2));

        double leftBottomMan = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((Math.abs((double)x-(double)mLeftBottomPosX)),2)
                + Math.pow((Math.abs((double)y-(double)mLeftBottomPosY)),2));

        double rightBottomMan = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((Math.abs((double)x-(double)mRightBottomPosX)),2)
                + Math.pow((Math.abs((double)y-(double)mRightBottomPosY)),2));

        //Log.i(TAG,"leftTopMan: "+leftTopMan);
        //Log.i(TAG,"RightTopMan: "+rightTopMan);

        if (leftTopMan < 50){
            mLeftTopBool = true;
            mRightTopBool = false;
            mLeftBottomBool = false;
            mRightBottomBool = false;
        }
        else if (rightTopMan < 50){
            mLeftTopBool = false;
            mRightTopBool = true;
            mLeftBottomBool = false;
            mRightBottomBool = false;
        }
        else if (leftBottomMan < 50){
            mLeftTopBool = false;
            mRightTopBool = false;
            mLeftBottomBool = true;
            mRightBottomBool = false;
        }
        else if (rightBottomMan < 50){
            mLeftTopBool = false;
            mRightTopBool = false;
            mLeftBottomBool = false;
            mRightBottomBool = true;
        }

    }
    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public float getmLeftTopPosX(){
        return mLeftTopPosX;
    }
    public float getmLeftTopPosY(){
        return mLeftTopPosY;
    }
    public float getmRightTopPosX(){
        return mRightTopPosX;
    }
    public float getmRightTopPosY(){
        return mRightTopPosY;
    }
    public float getmLeftBottomPosX() {
        return mLeftBottomPosX;
    }
    public float getmLeftBottomPosY() {
        return mLeftBottomPosY;
    }
    public float getmRightBottomPosY() {
        return mRightBottomPosY;
    }
    public float getmRightBottomPosX() {
        return mRightBottomPosX;
    }
    public void setRec(Rect rec) {
        this.buttonRec = rec;
    }

    // calls the onDraw method, I used it in my app Translanguage OCR
    // because I have a thread that needs to invalidate, or redraw
    // you cannot call onDraw from a thread not the UI thread.
    public void setInvalidate() {
        invalidate();

    }
}
```

and by this code you capture the rectangular area

```
package com.domp.me;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;



import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;


public class CameraPreview extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private Preview mPreview; 
    private ImageView mTakePicture;
    private TouchView mView;
    Display mDisplay;
    DisplayMetrics mDisplayMetrics;
 AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    private boolean mAutoFocus = true;
    ImageButton hidingcrop;
    ImageButton showgrid;
    ImageButton hidegrid;
       private Animation animShow, animHide;
    com.domp.me.GridCrop grid;
    private boolean mFlashBoolean = false;
   private RelativeLayout relative;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccel;
    private boolean mInitialized = false;
    private float mLastX = 0;
    private float mLastY = 0;

    private float mLastZ = 0;
    private Rect rec = new Rect();
Camera mCamera;
    private int mScreenHeight;
    private int mScreenWidth;
    Toast t;
    private boolean mInvalidate = false;
    Animation ranim_clockwise, ranim_anticlockwise;
    private File mLocation = new File(Environment.
            getExternalStorageDirectory(),"DompitCrop.jpg");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crop);
        t.makeText(CameraPreview.this, "When Capturing Wait 4 Seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        t.makeText(CameraPreview.this, "Whe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).setGravity(mScreenWidth, mScreenWidth, mScreenHeight);
        if(t.makeText(CameraPreview.this, "Whe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).getView().isShown()){
            t.makeText(CameraPreview.this, "Whe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).cancel();
        }
        animShow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( this, R.anim.popup_show);
        animHide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( this, R.anim.wave_scale);
        relative = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
        relative.startAnimation(animHide);
        mTakePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.capture);
        ranim_clockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotate_clockwise);
        ranim_anticlockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rorate_anticlockwise);


        // the accelerometer is used for autofocus
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.
                SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccel = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.
                TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        // get the window width and height to display buttons
        // according to device screen size
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        mScreenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        mScreenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        // I need to get the dimensions of this drawable to set margins
        // for the ImageView that is used to take pictures
        Drawable mButtonDrawable = this.getResources().
        getDrawable(R.drawable.cam);



        // setting where I will draw the ImageView for taking pictures

        // rec is used for onInterceptTouchEvent. I pass this from the
        // highest to lowest layer so that when this area of the screen
        // is pressed, it ignores the TouchView events and passes it to
        // this activity so that the button can be pressed.
        rec.set((int)((double)mScreenWidth*.85),
                (int)((double)mScreenHeight*.10) ,
                (int)((double)mScreenWidth*.85)+mButtonDrawable.getMinimumWidth(), 
                (int)((double)mScreenHeight*.70)+mButtonDrawable.getMinimumHeight());
        mButtonDrawable = null;
        mTakePicture.setOnClickListener(previewListener);
        grid = (com.domp.me.GridCrop)findViewById(R.id.grid);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        hidingcrop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagecrope);
        hidingcrop.setOnClickListener(mylistener);
        btn.setOnClickListener(flashListener);
        // get our Views from the XML layout
        mPreview = (Preview) findViewById(R.id.preview);
        mView = (TouchView) findViewById(R.id.left_top_view);
        mView.setRec(rec);

    }

    // this is the autofocus call back
    private AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback(){

        public void onAutoFocus(boolean autoFocusSuccess, Camera arg1) {
            //Wait.oneSec();
            mAutoFocus = true;
        }};

        // with this I get the ratio between screen size and pixels
        // of the image so I can capture only the rectangular area of the
        // image and save it.
        public Double[] getRatio(){
            Size s = mPreview.getCameraParameters().getPreviewSize();
            double heightRatio = (double)s.height/(double)mScreenHeight;
            double widthRatio = (double)s.width/(double)mScreenWidth;
            Double[] ratio = {heightRatio,widthRatio};
            return ratio;
        }
        public void release(){
            mCamera.release();
            }
            private OnClickListener mylistener = new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        Camera camera = null;
                        try {
                            camera = Camera.open();
                        } catch (RuntimeException e) {

                        } finally {
                            if (camera != null) camera.release();
                            Intent i = new Intent(CameraPreview.this, BackScreenTry.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }


                }

                }

            ;
        // I am not using this in this example, but its there if you want
        // to turn on and off the flash.

        private OnClickListener flashListener = new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    mPreview.setFlash(true);

                mFlashBoolean = !mFlashBoolean;
            }

        };


        // This method takes the preview image, grabs the rectangular
        // part of the image selected by the bounding box and saves it.
        // A thread is needed to save the picture so not to hold the UI thread.
        private OnClickListener previewListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    mPreview.setCameraFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);

                    Thread tGetPic = new Thread( new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            Double[] ratio = getRatio();
                            int left = (int) (ratio[1]*(double)mView.getmLeftTopPosX());
                            // 0 is height
                            int top = (int) (ratio[0]*(double)mView.getmLeftTopPosY());

                            int right = (int)(ratio[1]*(double)mView.getmRightBottomPosX());

                            int bottom = (int)(ratio[0]*(double)mView.getmRightBottomPosY());

                            savePhoto(mPreview.getPic(left,top,right,bottom));
                            mAutoFocus = true;




                        } 
                    });
                    tGetPic.start();
                    Wait.oneSec();
                    Intent i = new Intent(CameraPreview.this, AnimationScreenForCrop.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                    }

                }

        ;



        public boolean savePhoto(Bitmap bm) {
            System.gc();
            FileOutputStream image = null;
            try {
                image = new FileOutputStream(mLocation);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, image);

            int h = bm.getHeight();
            int w = bm.getWidth();


            return false;

        }

        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            final int action = ev.getAction();
            boolean intercept = false;
            switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                float x = ev.getX();
                float y = ev.getY();
                // here we intercept the button press and give it to this 
                // activity so the button press can happen and we can take 
                // a picture.
                if ((x >= rec.left) && (x <= rec.right) && (y>=rec.top) && (y<=rec.bottom)){
                    intercept = true;
                }
                break;
            }
            return intercept;
        }

        // mainly used for autofocus to happen when the user takes a picture
        // I also use it to redraw the canvas using the invalidate() method
        // when I need to redraw things.
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {



            if (mInvalidate == true){
                mView.invalidate();
                mInvalidate = false;
            }
            float x = event.values[0];
            float y = event.values[1];
            float z = event.values[2];
            if (!mInitialized){
                mLastX = x;
                mLastY = y;
                mLastZ = z;
                mInitialized = true;
            }
            float deltaX  = Math.abs(mLastX - x);
            float deltaY = Math.abs(mLastY - y);
            float deltaZ = Math.abs(mLastZ - z);

            if (deltaX > .5 && mAutoFocus){ //AUTOFOCUS (while it is not autofocusing)
                mAutoFocus = false;
                mPreview.setCameraFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
            }
            if (deltaY > .5 && mAutoFocus){ //AUTOFOCUS (while it is not autofocusing)
                mAutoFocus = false;
                mPreview.setCameraFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
            }

            if (deltaZ > .5 && mAutoFocus){ //AUTOFOCUS (while it is not autofocusing) */
                mAutoFocus = false;
                mPreview.setCameraFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
            }

            mLastX = x;
            mLastY = y;
            mLastZ = z;

        }


        // extra overrides to better understand app lifecycle and assist debugging
        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            //Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy()");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            //Log.i(TAG, "onPause()");
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccel, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
            //Log.i(TAG, "onResume()");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onRestart() {
            super.onRestart();
            //Log.i(TAG, "onRestart()");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            //Log.i(TAG, "onStop()");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            //Log.i(TAG, "onStart()");
        }
        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {

}
}
```

Enjoy:)

Comment: Can you help me to resolve `AlertDialogManager`, `com.domp.me.GridCrop grid` and `mPreview = (Preview) findViewById(R.id.preview);`

Comment: Your getting the gold code out of me haha:)by the way com.domp.me.GridCrop gives you a GRID like goggles made with my own:) where com.domp.me is the name of your package and GridCrop is the name of class where grid stands ill post them right now

Comment: Hehe:) Ya I know this code must have required a lot of efforts! I really appreciate your help

Comment: Lol i worked for this code like more than 4 months day and night non-sleeping and i got so heaps of bugs and all fixed image in GOLD code hehe:)my pleasure to help you out of struggle:)i know what it feels to struggle for code:)

Comment: This code is fantastic!Salute!I spent this whole time just reading n trying to understand it :) I think i got borderline of the logic but i have a long way to go before i could say that i understood it :)

Comment: I tried to execute the code and it worked wonders,but i can't find the captured image.When i pressed `capture` imageview, i got `D/skia﹕ onFlyCompress`. So the image was captured or not?

Comment: Lil im so happy i could make it easy and yeah check ur sd card location for donpitcrop named file if you wont find it try to change compress type of bitmap on mine it works you might use old api level so you can even not to compress at all and mainly that line refers to compression check codeline carefully again its long but you have too lo

Comment: Yes i checked n it was created. Thanks a lot,i hope i will be learning a lot of things from this :)

Comment: Awww your welcome im so haooy i could help you out:)

Comment: Just on another note,I was wondering where i was going wrong with `createBitmap()`. Some other questions suggested to conversion of `dpi` to `pixels` and then calling createBitmap.But even after doing so,the image is still getting cropped wrongly.Can you suggest some solution?